# Comparer not working in OrderB by?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, collections

I am trying to sort some strings using entity framework `OrderByDescending` or `OrderBy`
but some how it is not working, i need to use sort with string comparer.

Here is my Code:

```
public class MyStringComparer : IComparer<string> 
{
    CultureInfo culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("no");
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
            return string.Compare(x, y, true, culture);
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyStringComparer comparer = new MyStringComparer();
        List<string> name = new List<string> { "åtestå", "aaabc", "åtestå", "Basxas","xxxax" };
        name.OrderByDescending(x => x, comparer);
        name.ForEach( x => {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        });
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comparer is never called, what am I missing?

Result should be

> aaabc
>   Basxas
>   xxxax
>   åtestå
>   åtestå

But it is coming as

> åtestå
>   aaabc
>   åtestå
>   Basxas
>   xxxax

If there could be another way to do the same, please suggest.

Comment: Where is EF used? Is `name` just an example and a `DbSet` in "real code"?

Comment: Good point from chrfin, you can't expect your custom comparer to work in Entity Framework, since the SQL translation will fail.  In SQL Server, results are sorted using a "collation", the default collation is set by the installation of the database, but can be overridden if required.  You can, of course, return the results from the DB and sort them in .Net code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to read up on [LINQ deferred execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx).

Replace:

```
name.OrderByDescending(x=> x, comparer);
name.ForEach(x => { Console.WriteLine(x); });
```

With:

```
var ordered = name.OrderByDescending(x=> x, comparer).ToList();
ordered.Foreach(Console.WriteLine);
```

**Explanation:**

`name.OrderByDescending(x => x, comparer)` returns an `IEnumerable<String>` and the comparer is not utilized until the collection is enumerated. You are however not storing the result of this operation, so it never happens.

Comment: That's right, the Comparer is only executed when results of the OrderByDescending are enumerated.  However, now that the comparer is actually getting called you *still* get the same result, so maybe your expectation of ordering is incorrect, since your expected result is "OrderBy".